# 'Router' from 'react-router-dom' that uses custom history object doesn't change view on Route change [React-Router-Dom v6]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Im trying a simple implement a simple react app that uses 'Router' from react-router-dom that uses custom history object to navigate. But it seems like in the new react version they have made some changes that break the existing react code written in react 17.
The code below doesn't change the view or renders a component, but I can see that the URL is changing.

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import './config';
import { Link, Routes, Route, Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import Shellone from './shell-component/shell-one';
import Shelltwo from './shell-component/shell-two';
import history from './history';

const Home = () => {
  return (
  <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <Link to="/"><button>Home</button></Link>
        <Link to="/one"><button>Component One</button></Link>
        <Link to="/two"><button>Component Two</button></Link>
  </header>)
}

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <Router navigator={history} location={history.location}>
        <Routes> 
            <Route path="/" element={ <Home /> } />
            <Route path="/one" element={ <Shellone /> } />
            <Route path="/two" element={ < Shelltwo /> } />
        </Routes>
        </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The above code works with 'BrowserRouter'.

Comment: Your code is close. Missing is a bit of lifecycle logic to update/rerender the UI when the route changes.